# Flyspell not loading automatically with LaTeX file

Tags: emacs, hunspell, flyspell

Trying to use Flyspell with LaTeX files. Setup looks like this:

```
(require 'ispell)
(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/hunspell") ;; From Homebrew, version 1.4.1
(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '("de_DE_OLDSPELL" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" t ("-d" "de_DE_OLDSPELL") nil iso-8859-1))
(setq ispell-dictionary "de_DE_OLDSPELL")
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

Won't load automatically when opening a text (or LaTeX) file, but works fine when loaded manually. How to get Flyspell to load automatically? Probably a simple answer, but I've been going in circles for a while with this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is [a known problem](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveSpell) in interactions between Hunspell and Emacs 24.4+. If Hunspell does not have a dictionary available that corresponds to the value of LANG in Emacs, the autoconfigure will fail. So, set DICTIONARY to the base file name of a dictionary that *is* available. Hunspell usually insists on an English dictionary, so `(setenv DICTIONARY "en_US")` or the like should do the trick. That particular bit of code worked for me.